# How to load AJAX in react

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Im trying to get my json result into my react code

The code looks like the following

```
_getComments() {

 const commentList = "AJAX JSON GOES HERE"

return commentList.map((comment) => {
  return ( 
           <Comment
           author={comment.author}
           body={comment.body}
           avatarUrl={comment.avatarUrl}
           key={comment.id} />);
  });
}
```

How do i fetch AJAX into this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First**, to fetch the data using AJAX, you have a few options:

- The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), which will work out of the box in [some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) (you can use a polyfill to get it working in other browsers as well). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39067241/1783792) for an example implementation.
- A library for data fetching (which generally work in all modern browsers). [Facebook recommends](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) the following:

  - [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)
  - [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest)
  - [react-ajax](https://github.com/yuanyan/react-ajax)
  - [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)
  - [request](https://github.com/request/request)

**Next**, you need to use it somewhere in your React component. Where and how you do this will depend on your specific application and component, but generally I think there's two scenarios to consider:

1. Fetching initial data (e.g. a list of users).
2. Fetching data in response to some user interaction (e.g. clicking a 
   button to add more users).

**Fetching initial data** should be done in the life-cycle method [`componentDidMount()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). From the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html):

```
var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      username: '',
      lastGistUrl: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      var lastGist = result[0];
      this.setState({
        username: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.username}'s last gist is
        <a href={this.state.lastGistUrl}>here</a>.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />,
  mountNode
);
```

Here they use jQuery to fetch the data. While that works just fine, it's probably not a good idea to use such a big library (in terms of size) to perform such a small task.

**Fetching data in response to e.g. an action** can be done like this:

```
var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      users: []
    };
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest && this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  fetchNewUser: function () {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      var lastGist = result[0];
      var users = this.state.users
      users.push(lastGist.owner.login)
      this.setState({ users });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map(user => <div>{user}</div>)}
        <button onClick={this.fetchNewUser}>Get new user</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />,
  mountNode
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a look on the fetch API : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Lets say we want to fetch a simple list into our component.

```
export default MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            lst: []
        };

        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch('url')
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ lst: res });
        });
    }
}
```

We are fetching the data from the server, and we get the result from the service, we convert is to json, and then we set the result which will be the array in the state.

Comment: The data fetching is fine, but you shouldn't do it in the constructor, but rather in componentDidMount.

Comment: I didnt do it anywhere i just binded the function's context to the component in order to access the state in tje function. It is up to him to decide where to use

Comment: Oh my bad, looked at it too fast.  Adding something about where to use the code could probably be helpful though. And if this this is done in e.g. componentDidMount, that binding isn't necessary.

Comment: Well that depends if he wants to fetch once the component mounts or on click, so thats for him to decide, im just providing the way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.get` or `jQuery.ajax` in componentDidMount:

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
...
    componentDidMount() {
        $.get('your/url/here').done((loadedData) => {
            this.setState({data: loadedData});
    });
...
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt use jquery if youre using react these are 2 completly different things with different principles and approach and you dont want to overload your project with 2 big laibraries like that

Comment: Yes, it's not good idea to use both libraries in a project but using jquery and react together isn't big sin. Facebook uses a such example in React's tutorial. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#updating-state

Answer (score -2):

First I'd like to use fetchAPI now install of ajax like zepto's ajax,the render of reactjs is asyn,you can init a state in the constructor,then change the state by the data from the result of fetch.

Comment: IE is still a very popular browser. Until we know most of our customers are off IE11 we have to use something like Axios since fetch API is sadly not supported.