# "Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted." when using Axios with local API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to console.log an API hosted on my LocalHost. It is a simple PHP API that is running on XAMPP on another port separate from React. Axios is then importing the API and assigning it to the 'products' state.

Everytime I console.log the API, it displays fine in the console. However, it loads Twice. And in-between both console logs, is the full error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the App component.
```

How can I modify my code to get rid of this error entirely?

App.js

```
import axios from "axios"
import React from "react"

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost/api/`,
})

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    }
    api.get("/").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({ products: res.data })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* {this.state.products.map((product) => (
          <div>
            <h1>{product.id}</h1>
            <h2>{product.subproduct}</h2>
            <img src={product.img_url} class="product_img"></img>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))} */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Put your call in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. This is well-covered [in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load AJAX in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066972/how-to-load-ajax-in-react)

Comment: Thanks, sorry, new to react!

Comment: No prob, just make sure you work your way thru the official tutorial and check the React FAQs before posting here. The official React documentation is actually really good, way better than a lot of other projects, good chance it has what you need.